# Set WSUS Proxy with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, proxy

I'm not able to set the WSUS proxy with powershell.

I have tried diffrent solutions like:

```
.\WsusUtil.exe configuresslproxy "IP" "Port" -enable

.\upddwnldcfg.exe /s:IP:Port /allusers

netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie #the IE settings are already configured
```

None of this commnds work.

I also tired wsusutility but I think the configuresslproxy is the wrong command. I don't use ssl.

this screenshot shows the GUI setting which I want to overwrite:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have test environment right now to check will it work but you can try:

```
$proxyname = "168.192.0.0"
$proxyport = 8080

$wsussrv = get-wsusserver
$wsussrvconfig = $wsussrv.GetConfiguration()
$wsussrvconfig.ProxyName = $proxyname
$wsussrvconfig.ProxyServerPort = $proxyport
$wsussrvconfig.UseProxy = $true
$wsussrvconfig.Save()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add the $wsussrvconfig.UseProxy property. After that it works. I will accept it as answer when you update the answer with the missing property.